# Changes reflect in all the dropdowns which are bound to same source

Tags: angularjs

I have two dropdown on my page. They both have the same datasource. 
The problem I am facing is selecting an item in one dropdown affect the other also. HOw can I avoid that.

HTML:

```
 <!--Locations Dropdown Begin-->
                    <div style="display:inline-block">
                        <div class="dropdown">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <span>{{ selectedItem ? selectedItem.Label : 'SELECT LOCATION' }}</span>
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li ng-repeat="location in Locations"
                                    <a ng-click="dropboxitemselected(location)">
                                        {{location.Label}}
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--Locations Dropdown End-->
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DBbrhJCGDYrR5xiQMlPp?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Could store `selectedItem` as array (or object) and add array index (or object key) argument to your ng-click function

```
     <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <span>{{ selectedItem[0] ? selectedItem.label[0] : 'SELECT LOCATION' }}</span>
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li ng-repeat="location in Locations">
          <a ng-click="dropboxitemselected(location,0)">
                                    {{location.label}}
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

JS

```
$scope.selectedItem=[];

$scope.dropboxitemselected = function(item, index) {
  $scope.selectedItem[index] = item;
};

// OR

$scope.selectedItem={loc_1:null, loc_2:null};

$scope.dropboxitemselected = function(item, loc) {
  $scope.selectedItem[loc] = item;
};
```

Comment: you was faster on posting the same idea ! ;)